# Getting all the parent (and their parent) of a given child node in a MySQL relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would love to get a code that does the same operation just the opposite. ZA accept all parents (and their parents) to the root.

This is the code that brings all the kids:

```
select  Child
from    (select * from tchilds
         order by parent, child) s,
        (select @pv2 := '6') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent, @pv2) > 0
and     @pv2 := concat(@pv2,',', child);
```

And I need the code without CTE,
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you upgrade to MySQL 8.x to use CTEs. Using variables is being deprecated. The solution using variables has been posted several times here, but none of them works for all cases.

Comment: Can't do without CTE? I can not update the version of mysql, I need a solution without CTE.

Comment: If you are stuck with MySQL 5.x maybe a stored procedure can get the result programatically.

Comment: Ok, I'd love to hear how by procedure?

Comment: But why finding children is possible and parents are not?

Comment: someone?, please...